# Spark Scala Error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.collection.mutable.Buffer$.empty()Lscala/collection/GenTraversable

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I am facing following issue while read CSV file using Intellij Scala.

**Error Message:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.collection.mutable.Buffer$.empty()Lscala/collection/GenTraversable;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSessionExtensions.<init>(SparkSessionExtensions.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.<init>(SparkSession.scala:780)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.builder
```

**Source Code:**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
object broadcastright {

   def main(args : Array[String]): Unit = {
     val spark = SparkSession
       .builder()
       .master("local")
       .appName("Read CSV File")
       .getOrCreate()

     val df = spark.read
       .option("header", "true")
       .option("delimiter", ",")
       .option("inferSchema", "false")
       .load("src\\main\\resources\\people.csv")

     df.show()
   }
  }
```

**Pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I am not sure what is the cause for this issue.

Comment: What version of scala u are using ??

Comment: is this issue fixed ?

Comment: No..still not yet..Using Spark-sdk-2.13.1

Comment: from pom.xml your spark uses scala version 2.12 & you have to use same scala version in ide also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If any version difference in spark libraries we will be getting lot of issue as some of methods might not be available in newer version or some new methods might not available in lower version of spark.

Please add same version of spark libraries in maven file. Also scala version in pom.xml and classpath scala version should match.

Answer (score 1):

You run into these type of issues if your Intellij is using incompatible Scala compiler version. This is a very common issue which happens within Intellij workspace if you are building Spark pipeline using Scala.

If you install Scala plugin in your Intellij, it installs a default version of SDK with it. You just have to make sure the installed version of Scala compiler/SDK is compatible with you Spark version.

For example you are using using ***Spark 3.x.x***, be assured that you have ***Scala 2.12.x*** compiler
Installed.

Process to fix the issue:

> File -> Project Structure -> Platform Settings -> Global Libraries ->
> +

1. Click on **+** icon

[image: Click on + icon]

2. Click on version on Scala you want to download. In my case Maven 2.12.2

[image: Maven Scala version]

3. Select Scala version from Dropdown and click ok. In my case 2.12.2

[image: Scala 2.12.2]

4. Tag your project against it.

[image]

5. This is how your configuration should look like.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Scala 2.13 was installed automatically on IntellijIDEA but the spark was running on Scala 2.12.

I removed Scala 2.13 from IntellijIDEA and installed Scala 2.12 using maven.